# Android : If-statement to display "correct" when user inputs value

Tags: android

I want the user to input the value 4 and have a TextView called result display that it's correct

Comment: That code really isn't helpful - post more of your code. Ideally the part that initialises the `result` variable, as well as the rest of your `case` statements.

Answer (score 1):

you are compare String and Editable

try "4".equals(ans.getText().toString())